# Identificación de problemas en Pagespeed Insights: Tiempo de respuesta del servidor y tareas largas del hilo principal

Tags: servidor, hilos, response

¡Hola a todos!

Recientemente realicé un [análisis en Pagespeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-fotov60-com/ouhe2z45s5?hl=es&form_factor=mobile) para mi sitio de WordPress y encontré dos problemas destacados que me gustaría resolver: el tiempo de respuesta del servidor y las tareas largas del hilo principal.

1. Tiempo de respuesta del servidor: Según el informe, el tiempo de respuesta inicial del servidor es de alrededor de 0,91 segundos, lo cual se considera lento. Sin embargo, cuando consulté al soporte técnico de mi servicio de alojamiento, me informaron que el tiempo de respuesta del servidor es en realidad más bajo. Me proporcionaron un enlace a un archivo estático (https://fotov60.com/license.txt) para verificarlo, y efectivamente, el tiempo de respuesta fue más rápido en ese caso. Estoy utilizando la versión 6.2 de WordPress y el plugin Litespeed Cache, alojado en un servidor LiteSpeed. Me gustaría entender por qué el informe de Pagespeed Insights muestra un tiempo de respuesta más alto a pesar de que el acceso a archivos estáticos parece ser más rápido. ¿Existen otros factores que podrían estar influyendo en el tiempo de respuesta del servidor en mi sitio de WordPress considerando mi configuración específica?
2. Tareas largas del hilo principal: Pagespeed Insights también me muestra una lista de cinco tareas largas del hilo principal. Entiendo que estas tareas pueden contribuir a la latencia y afectar el rendimiento general del sitio. Me gustaría identificar las tareas específicas y explorar cómo puedo evitarlas o mejorar su ejecución para reducir la carga en el hilo principal. A continuación, se muestra la lista de plugins que tengo instalados en mi sitio de WordPress:

- query-monitor/query-monitor.php
- akismet/akismet.php
- apcu-manager/apcu-manager.php
- auto-image-attributes-from-filename-with-bulk-updater/iaff_image-attributes-from-filename.php
- broken-link-checker/broken-link-checker.php
- classic-widgets/classic-widgets.php
- comments-cleaner/comments-cleaner.php
- decalog/decalog.php
- delete-expired-transients/delete-expired-transients.php
- freesoul-deactivate-plugins/freesoul-deactivate-plugins.php
- google-site-kit/google-site-kit.php
- https-redirection/https-redirection.php
- indexnow/indexnow-url-submission.php
- jetpack-boost/jetpack-boost.php
- jetpack-protect/jetpack-protect.php
- jetpack/jetpack.php
- litespeed-cache/litespeed-cache.php
- ninjafirewall/ninjafirewall.php
- performance-lab/load.php
- seo-by-rank-math/rank-math.php
- ssl-insecure-content-fixer/ssl-insecure-content-fixer.php
- theme-check/theme-check.php
- tinymce-advanced/tinymce-advanced.php
- transients-manager/transients-manager.php
- wordfence/wordfence.php
- wp-issuu/issuu-embed.php
- wp-sweep/wp-sweep.php
- wp-youtube-lyte/wp-youtube-lyte.php

Mis preguntas son:

1. Dado que el tiempo de respuesta del servidor parece ser más

bajo cuando se accede a archivos estáticos como el proporcionado (https://fotov60.com/license.txt), ¿por qué el informe de Pagespeed Insights muestra un tiempo de respuesta más alto? ¿Existen otros factores, además de los plugins, que podrían estar influyendo en el tiempo de respuesta del servidor en mi sitio de WordPress considerando mi configuración específica?

2. ¿Cómo puedo identificar las tareas específicas en el hilo principal que están contribuyendo a la latencia? ¿Existen herramientas o técnicas recomendadas para analizar y mejorar la ejecución de estas tareas?

Agradezco cualquier orientación o sugerencia para resolver estos problemas y mejorar el rendimiento de mi sitio de WordPress.

¡Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Es difícil darte una respuesta exacta a lo que buscas. Acá va la mía.

1. Tu sitio esta super bien en métricas, no busques el 100% que te vas a estresar.
2. Acá te dejo otros test que se ven bien. [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.fotov60.com/ZvPyQ5kn/) y [webspeedtest](https://webspeedtest.cloudinary.com/results/230605_AiDc4G_7VE), puedes buscar otras referencias también.
3. Con el tema de el **tiempo de respuesta inicial del servidor**, te diré que entre mas plugins tengas, tu sitio va a tardar mas en cargar, los test tipo Page Speed analizan todo, desde el inicio hasta el final de la carga. Yo no tendría mayores traumas por este tema.
4. Tienes demasiados plugins instalados y algunos son redundantes o podrías instalar un plugin que haga varias de las actividades que manejan plugins separados. Por ejemplo, con WP-Optimize puedes controlar temas de cache, limpieza de base, compresión de imágenes entre otras cosas. Con Rank Math puedes ver tema SEO, Redirecciones, Monitor 404 y mucho más.
5. Usas plugins que saturan tu sitio. **query-monitor** genera mucho trafico analizando cada petición a la DB. Yo que tu lo quitaría, lo puedes tener para momentos puntuales pero después quítalo. Akismet es otra cosa que no lo necesitas.

En fin, para poder decirte todo lo de los plugins que tienes sería bastante largo. Pero puedes iniciar por el punto 4 y 5.

Ahora, si lo que quieres es que a nivel propio te digan como poder optimizar más o mejor tu sitio, puedes solicitar que alguien te proporcione ese servicio.

Comment: Soy consciente de que buscar puntuaciones del 100% puede ser estresante, pero mi intención va mas en el sentido de encontrar la causa y comprender el porque, que en encontrar alguien que me de una solución. Se que tengo muchos plugins, pero algunos estan porque tienen una función concreta que hacen mejor que el principal que tengo, como Litespeed cache para la cache y la optimizacion de imágenes. Pero me gustaria poder saber y comprender porque en el informe aparece el dominio 5 veces con diferentes duraciones. El informe de Insights no permite profundizar mucho en ello.